# Aws Dynamodb - how to reuse ScalableTarget of auto-scaling in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to add auto-scaling to multiple Dynamodb tables, since all the tables would have the same pattern for the auto-scaling configuration.

I can of course create scalableTarget again and again but it’s repetitive.

I was wondering if it is possible to re-use the scalable targets

```
"DDBTable": {
   "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
   "Properties": {
       "TableName": "Banner_v1", 
       ...
   }
},
 
 "WriteCapacityScalableTarget": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget",
        "Properties": {
            "MaxCapacity": 15,
            "MinCapacity": 5,
            "ResourceId": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "/",
                    [
                        "table",
                        {
                            "Ref": "DDBTable"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "RoleARN": {
              "Fn::ImportValue" : "ScalingRoleArn"
            },
            "ScalableDimension": "dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits",
            "ServiceNamespace": "dynamodb"
        }
    },   
      "WriteScalingPolicy": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
        "Properties": {
            "PolicyName": "WriteAutoScalingPolicy",
            "PolicyType": "TargetTrackingScaling",
            "ScalingTargetId": {
                "Ref": "WriteCapacityScalableTarget"
            },
            "TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration": {
                "TargetValue": 50,
                "ScaleInCooldown": 60,
                "ScaleOutCooldown": 60,
                "PredefinedMetricSpecification": {
                    "PredefinedMetricType": "DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Tried this but not working.

```
"WriteCapacityScalableTarget": {
   "Type": "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget",
   "Properties": {
       "ResourceId": {
       ...
           "Fn::Join": [
               "/",
               [
                   "table",
                   {
                       "Ref": "DDBTable"
                   },
                   "table",
                   {
                     "Ref": "AnotherTable2"
                   }
               ]
           ]
       },
       ...
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can of course create scalableTarget again and again but it’s repetitive

Using plain CFN, this is how you have to do it. The reason is that [ResourceId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-applicationautoscaling-scalabletarget.html#cfn-applicationautoscaling-scalabletarget-resourceid) is just a `string`, rather then a `list of strings`.

The only other alternative in CFN would be to use [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or [macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html). In both cases you would have to develop some lambda function to do automatically the repetitive stuff.

Comment: So if i have 10 table, i have to create 10 scalableTarget?

Comment: @CCCC Unfortunately, yes.